# Plot fitted line within certain range R

Tags: r, plot, lm, par

Using R, I would like to plot a linear relationship between two variables, but I would like the fitted line to be present only within the range of the data.

For example, if I have the following code, I would like the line to exist only from x and y values of 1:10 (with default parameters this line extends beyond the range of data points).

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
plot(x,y)
abline(lm(y~x))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of using `abline()`, (a) save the fitted model, (b) use `predict.lm()` to find the fitted y-values corresponding to x=1 and x=10, and then (c) use `lines()` to add a line between the two points:

```
f <- lm(y~x)
X <- c(1, 10)
Y <- predict(f, newdata=data.frame(x=X))

plot(x,y)
lines(x=X, y=Y)
```

Answer (score 28):

In addition to using `predict` with `lines` or `segments` you can also use the `clip` function with `abline`:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
plot(x,y)
clip(1,10, -100, 100)
abline(lm(y~x))
```

Comment: +1, because it works with any line, also abline(), without using the hack with predict(). This way one can, e.g., also trim ablines that extend to the margins of a plot, but only to one side, e.g. to the right, not to the left.

Comment: This is a far better answer than the accepted one. Much simpler, and actually operates on the visual representation, as desired, rather than making some weird new line representation using `predict`

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using predict.

You can predict on specific values of x (see ?predict)

```
x<-1:10
y<-1:10
plot(x,y)
new <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 5, 0.5))
lines(new$x, predict(lm(y~x), new))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The plotrix library has the `ablineclip()` function for just this:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
plot(x,y)
ablineclip(lm(y~x),x1=1,x2=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the `segments` function (doc [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/segments.html)).

Say you estimated the line, and you got an intercept of `a` and a slope of `b`. Thus, your fitted function is `y = a + bx`.

Now, say you want to show the line for x between `x0` and `x1`. Then, the following code plots your line:

```
# inputs

a <- 0.5
b <- 2

x0 <- 1
x1 <- 5

# graph

plot(c(0,5), c(0,5), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", bty='l')
segments(x0, a+b*x0, x1, a+b*x1)
```

**Simply replace the values of** `a, b, x0, x1` **with those of your choosing**.

[image]

---

For those like me who came to this question wanting to plot a line for an arbitrary pair of numbers (and not those that fit a given regression), the following code is what you need:

```
plot(c(0,5), c(0,5), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", bty='l')
segments(x0, yo, x1, y1)
```

**Simply replace the values of** `x0, y0, x1, y1` **with those of your choosing**.